# Completely positive maps and symmetric states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, symmetry, group-theory, density-operator

Let $\mathcal{N}$ be a completetely positive trace preserving map (aka a quantum channel) acting on a finite dimensional system $\mathrm{A}$, and let $\pi$ denote the maximally mixed state on $\mathrm{A}$. 
Given two isomorphic systems $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{A}'$, let $\sigma$ denote the maximally mixed state on the symmetric subspace (under permutation of $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{A}'$).
I am trying to understand under which conditions on $\mathcal{N}$ the following holds:
$$
[ \mathcal{N}(\pi) \otimes \mathcal{N}(\pi) , (\mathcal{N} \otimes \mathcal{N})(\sigma) ] = 0 \, .
$$
For instance, this equality holds if $\mathcal{N}$ is the identical channel, or a depolarizing channel $\mathcal{N}(\rho) = p \rho + (1-p)\pi$.

Thanks a lot of your help!

PS: if you are interested, I need this in relation to this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06038